Why compiler complains on using a reference to a var passed as a parameter?
My code:
#include <stdio.h>

void adding(int a,int b,int& sum);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    
    int sum = 0;
    int a = 5;
    int b = 6;
    printf("Sum of %d and %d = ", a, b);
    adding(a,b,sum);
    printf("\n%d", sum);

    return 0;
}

void adding(int a, int b, int& sum) 
{
    sum = a + b; 
    printf("%d", sum);
}

I just want to see that passing reference to var(sum) as parameter to a function, where this var is going to change it's value -> will change it value in main() as well. But i'm getting this:
error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘&’ token
However it's working correctly in C book i'm reading.
My platform: Ubuntu 22.04
GCC version: 13.2.0
IDE: VS Code

What book is this? A reference is not valid in C. Instead, pass a pointer to the value. If you want to use references, you'll need to use C++.

It would be nice if you would clarify whether this is a C or C++ textbook. If it's supposed to be C, get a new book.

int& sum is not standard grammar for C. In C++, it declares sum to be a reference.
In C, to provide a function with access to an object, you declare the parameter to be a pointer, as with int *sum, and, in the call to the function, you pass the address of the object, as with adding(a, b, &sum). Then, inside the function, you use * with the parameter name to refer to the pointed-to object, as with *sum = a + b;.
If the book is a C book and not a C++ book, then it is wrong.
